# Adding text below image in staggeredgridview in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add text in StaggeredGridView below image, but having trouble getting the alignment correct. Below code shows images correctly but when i add text to it, it will be overflow. I tried increasing height of it but didn't help. How can i get both Image and Text added to below view.

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: kIsWeb ? 4 : 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 12,
              mainAxisSpacing: 12,
              itemCount: myImageAndCaption.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    tileAction(myImageAndCaption[index][1]);
                    print("Container clicked" + myImageAndCaption[index][1]);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                        child: Image.asset(myImageAndCaption[index][0],
                            fit: BoxFit.fill)
                        ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                return new StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1 : 0.7);
              }),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Column` and set `Expaned flex` for `Image` and `Text` 
code snippet

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 9,
          child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
              child: Image.network(myImageAndCaption[index],
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        ),
        Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("title")),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  List<String> myImageAndCaption = [
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=10",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=11",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=12",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=13",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=14"
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          crossAxisCount: kIsWeb ? 4 : 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 12,
          mainAxisSpacing: 12,
          itemCount: myImageAndCaption.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                /*tileAction(myImageAndCaption[index][1]);
                print("Container clicked" + myImageAndCaption[index][1]);*/
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 9,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                          child: Image.network(myImageAndCaption[index],
                              fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                    ),
                    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("title")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
            return new StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1 : 0.7);
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chunhunghan we get the desired output with this code but the scale of images doesn't give good view all alignment are off, my intention here is not to breast 1:07 scale.

Comment: I do not have your picture. can not reproduce. can you try change BoxFit,